# How to embed every test in a wrapper logic?

Tags: java, testing, junit, test-runner

Given the requirement that every junit test have to run in the following wrapper:

```java
@Test
public void testFooBar() {
    SpecialLogic.runWith(new SpecialLogic("blah", "foo", ANYTHING), () -> {
        // my test 
    });
}
```

I am trying to avoid adding `SpecialLogic.runWith(...)` for each test.

Is there any possibility by using @BeforeEach or any other way?

Otherwise, there is much of duplicated code:

```java
@Test
public void testFooBar_2() {
    SpecialLogic.runWith(new SpecialLogic("blah", "foo", ANYTHING), () -> {
        // my test logic 2
    });
}

@Test
public void testFooBar_3() {
    SpecialLogic.runWith(new SpecialLogic("blah", "foo", ANYTHING), () -> {
        // my test logic 3
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Write your custom Runner, all the tests will have to run with this runner.
   This may be inappropriate if you already use another runner (say for spring or mockito)
2. Write your own Rule. The rule is a little bit newer way of doing what you've asked for, 
   and it doesn't "occupy" the slot of a runner which can be only one.

   public final class SampleRule implements TestRule {

   ```
   @Override public Statement apply(final Statement base, 
     final Description description) {
     return new Statement() {
       @Override public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
         // do your stuff before actually running the test
         try {
           base.evaluate(); // This line actually runs the test.
         } finally {
           // do your stuff after running a test
         }
       }
     };}}
   ```

[Here](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/writing-your-own-junit-rule-3df41997b10c) is one of numerous guides for writing Rules:

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should implement your own `TestRunner` to wrap your custom logic around each test method call. There is an [article over at Baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-4-custom-runners) explaining how this works.

Answer (score 0):

@Before and @After?  It won't use closures but should be functionally the same.

https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Before.html
https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/After.html